# vim.keymap.set issue

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I've tried to make a key map as follows:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('x', '<leader>n', function() -- Here <leader> is <Space>
    line1r, line1c  = unpack(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_mark(0, "<"))
    line2r, line2c = unpack(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_mark(0, ">"))
    print("line1r = " .. line1r .. "; line2r = " .. line2r)
  end, { noremap = true })
```

(Select some lines and print the first line number and the last line number)

When I select some lines in visual mode and type `<leader>`, [which-key](https://github.com/folke/which-key.nvim) shows `n` indicating this map exists.

However, it does not print `line 1= <some number>; line2= <some number>` when I type `n`, and it still stays in visual mode.

I'm not sure where is the wrong point.

Is there something I missed?

---

[Updated 1]

I've tried to make a whole new `init.lua` which only contains the following setting

```lua
vim.g.mapleader = ' ' -- Set leader as <Space>
vim.keymap.set('x', '<leader>n', function()
    line1r, _  = unpack(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_mark(0, "<"))
    line2r, __ = unpack(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_mark(0, ">"))
    print("line1r = " .. line1r .. "; line2r = " .. line2r)
  end, { noremap = true })
```

And it still doesn't work. That's weird.

[image]

By the way, my environment info:

```
- NVIM v0.9.1
  Build type: RelWithDebInfo
  LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
- OS: Windows 10
```

---

[Updated 2]

Using `:message`, it does record the printing result(s) it should have shown when the key mapping is triggered. However, these printing result does not appear exactly when the mapping is triggered. :-(

By the way, nvim seems to record the previous position of marks `'<` and `'>` rather than the "current" position. I think this may be discussed on another new question/post.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mapping look good.

But you have mapped against `<leader>n` which is by default: <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>

Unless you have define: `g:mapleader`.

You can know the value of `g:mapleader` by running the following Neovim command:

```
echo "'" . g:mapleader . "'"
```

Some people (including myself) and some distributions (including NvChad, LunarVim, LazyVim, AstroVim) defines `g:mapleader` to <kbd>Space</kbd>

In such case `<leader>n` corresponds to <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>

The result of the `print` call should be visible as the output of the following `Neovim` command

```
:messages
```

I you want to see the messages when they are triggered in Visual mode you have to increase the room for them with:

```
:set cmdheight=2
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've defined `<leader>` using `vim.g.mapleader = ' '` in the previous section. Checking `echo "'" . g:mapleader . "'"`, it gives `' '` meaning that `<leader>` is `<Space>`. Furthermore, the result of `:verbose xmap <Space>n` shows `x <Space>n  * <Lua {the path of the file setting this mapping} Lua>`. I think `<leader>`  should be `<Space>` as I expect. But when I try this mapping, it still doesn't work and stays in visual mode. 

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. When I try on my version it works well. Did you try with with a very simplifier version of `init.lua`?  What if you start Neovim with `nvim --clean`?

Comment: Hi. I've tried your suggestion and updated/edited the post. The conclusion is: it doesn't work. 

Comment: How do you select? Using `v` and some move or using the mouse?

Comment: Keystroke `v` without using mouse.

Comment: I'm lost :-/ Do you confirm that you type [space][n]?

Comment: In this .gif picture, I first type `v<Right><Right>` for selecting some characters, press the `<Space>` key on the keyboard and then press key `n` trying to trigger the mapping. The result shows in that .gif picture. Is any step I doing wrong? 

Comment: What is your run the command `:messages`? The messages are sometime hidden (in particular in visual mode). You maybe to list them using the `:messages` command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `:message` does show the printing result I expect, while the printing result does not appear when I tried to trigger the key mapping.  
I update the post and upload the .gif picture to show what happens when I tried to trigger the mapping.

Comment: I believe the mapping is correctly triggered but the messages are hidden in visual mode.

Comment: Hmm... so it is necessary to explicitly make the current buffer leaving visual mode (so that the message will not be hidden by `-- VISUAL --`) ?

Comment: Unless you increase the message root by changing `cmdheight` ;-). But why do you need to see these messages?

Comment: In my case, I just would like to create a key mapping triggered in visual mode, and it can show some information in command line. But I don't expect that nvim will stay in visual mode. 
 `:set cmdheight` does make it show the information. Thanks.
By the way, is it possible to "*dynamically* set `cmdheight`"? For example, `:set cmdheight=2` only takes effect in some step of the keymapping. When the keymapping is ended, it gets `cmdheight` back to `:set cmdheight=1`.

Comment: You can do all the actions in the mapping in particular `vim.o.cmdheight = 2` is the lua version of `:set cmdheight=2`.